# numba.typeinfer.TypingError: Untyped global name 'child_launch' when using CUDA Dynamic Parallelism in Python ( Anaconda ) on NVIDIA GPU

Tags: python, cuda, dynamic-parallelism

My code is here:

```
import numpy as np
from numbapro import cuda

@cuda.autojit
def child_launch(data):
    data[cuda.threadIdx.x] = data[cuda.threadIdx.x] + 100

@cuda.autojit
def parent_launch(data):
    data[cuda.threadIdx.x] = cuda.threadIdx.x
    cuda.syncthreads()

    if cuda.threadIdx.x == 0:
        child_launch[1, 256](data)
        cuda.synchronize()

    cuda.syncthreads()

data = np.zeros(256)
print data
parent_launch[ 1, 256 ](data)
print data
```

The running result is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
......
numba.typeinfer.TypingError: Untyped global name 'child_launch'
File "PythonOpenMPTestMain.py", line 14
```

I just don't know why I can't launch the child kernel. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you need to set `device=True` in the `child_launch` decorator, no? I got the same error and am trying to figure it out

Comment: @G.Meyer: dynamic parallelism was not and is not supported by the numba compiler

Answer (score 1):

> I just don't know why I can't launch the child kernel.

Because it is not (even in mid 2018) supported.

Quoting from the Numba 0.39 [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/overview.html)

> Numba does not implement all features of CUDA, yet. Some missing
>   features are listed below:
>
> - dynamic parallelism
> - texture memory